# add element to "this.$el" in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm wondering is any simple way to add some element to this.$el in Backbone. 
I can't fire event search beacause button is outside my this.$el. 
Do You know any correct solution?

Example:

**html**

```
  <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="search">Search</a></li>
  </ul>   
  <div class="contener">  <div class="articles"></div> </div>
```

**js**

```
  var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $(".contener"),
        events: {
              "click .search"       : "search"
        },
        search: function() {
            //some code here
         }
 })
```

Comment: what's the error? It seems right for me.

Comment: I don't have any error :) , but I can't fire event search. You know, it is outside a contener, and contener is my el :).
Is any way to add this link "search" to main contener in Backbone?

Comment: Why are you trying to listen to events from a non-child? Why not have a separate view for that `<ul>` and possibly an event aggregator to help broadcast the events to the rest of the application?

Comment: Maybe creating an App View concept may help. The App View will listen to events and take action to invoke other views that are contained within it.

Comment: bvoleti thank You. I don't think about it ;) 
mu is too short  thanks for Your questions. For me are partly answers :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add such events manually:

```
var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".contener"),
    initialize: function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.search', _.bind(this.search, this));
        //$('.search').on('click', _.bind(this.search, this));
    },
    search: function() {
        //some code here
    }
})
```